# Where to start relearning stats?

Tags: references, inference

I am a new data scientist , BS mathematics, MS quantitative analysis I want to have a really sound understanding of probability and statistics.

I am currently reading Introduction to mathematical statistics by Hogg 5th edition and also have a few other any suggestions on books to learn R in parallel to the theory presented in Introduction to Mathematical statistics?

Comment: Of interest to you:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414/introduction-to-statistics-for-mathematicians   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183164/statistics-for-engineers-resource-request       http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176807/book-recommendations-statistical-methods-in-the-social-sciences-for-someone-who/176837#176837    (This question might be a duplicate)

Comment: This site is rich with information and insights although they tend to be both fragmented and redundant. Another good, general website for all things statistical, ML and data science is Quora.com. That said, in my view one of the best resources out there along the lines of your query is Cosma Shalizi's pre-press publication *Advanced Data Analysis from an Elementary Point of View*. An ungated copy is available here ... http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/ADAfaEPoV.pdf

Comment: In MS quant analysis don't they teach stats? Why are you just starting to learn this?

Comment: @Aksal-Yeah absolutely  I learned stats, but I want a more mathematically rigorous understanding, I spend most of my day manipulating data and building models.  But I want a more rigorous understanding of things like Markov chains and Support vector machines. I can run and fit models that perform well but I feel more like a technician than a statistician.

Comment: DJ johnson thanks for the post I will look into these books !